# Use ANT to update a YML file with exec output

Tags: git, symfony, ant

I have an ANT task that currently writes the last git short commit hash to a version file:

```
<target name="write-version-file-uat">
    <exec executable="git" failonerror="true" output="${basedir}/some/path/version.html.twig">
        <arg value="rev-parse"/>
        <arg value="--short"/>
        <arg value="HEAD"/>
        <redirector>
            <outputfilterchain>
                <striplinebreaks />
                <trim />
            </outputfilterchain>
        </redirector>
    </exec>
</target>
```

I want to change this task to update a variable in a `version.yml.dist` file:

```
parameters:
    version: version_value
```

and output the new file to `version.yml`

```
parameters:
    version: this2is1ahash
```

How can I change the redirector to write to this variable?

Do I need to create a temporary version file and then run another task to get that content and update the variable or can I do it all at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have achieved the above using the following but I'm not sure it's the cleanest solution:

```
<target name="write-version-file">
    <exec executable="git" failonerror="true" output="${basedir}/some/path/version.yml">
        <arg value="describe"/>
        <arg value="--tags"/>
        <redirector>
            <outputfilterchain>
                <striplinebreaks />
                <trim />
                <prefixlines prefix="parameters: ${line.separator}    version: " />
            </outputfilterchain>
        </redirector>
    </exec>
</target>
```

Comment: Looks ok to me!